# What was Belgard's endgame?

Tags: the-musketeers

In S2E8 of the 2014 BBC series *The Musketeers* (very loosely adapted from Dumas's *The Three Musketeers*), one plotline that's been hinted at for a long time comes to a head when Porthos goes to meet his father, the Marquis de Belgard.

It turns out that Belgard's daughter and son-in-law Levesque are running a prostitution business from his estate, which the musketeers put a stop to. Belgard's own involvement is never proved or disproved, but Treville (who was a close friend of Belgard in their youth) believes he's part of it.

Belgard was lying to Porthos about his mother, but **what was he really trying to achieve?** Apparently he wasn't tricking Porthos into getting killed, because he himself shot Levesque. Surely he wouldn't think that Porthos would take over the lucrative prostitution business if he got the Levesques out of the way. If the other musketeers hadn't shown up in the nick of time, what was Belgard's plan? Kill Levesque and his thugs, and ... what? Enjoy a peaceful retirement with his newfound son? Let the prostitution business collapse? If he *was* involved with it as Treville suspected, that would seem out of character, and more in line with his fake father character that was all a lie.